# Comparing previous and next value in row csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file (.txt) containing detections from a CNN:

Example of CSV file:

```
filename,type,confidence,xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax  
27cz1_SLRM_0, barrow,87, 128, 176, 176, 224  
27cz1_SLRM_101, barrow,80, 480, 400, 512, 432  
27cz1_SLRM_103, celtic_field,85, 0, 112, 96, 256  
27cz1_SLRM_103, celtic_field,80, 256, 384, 384, 544  
27cz1_SLRM_103, celtic_field,80, 160, 96, 304, 272  
27cz1_SLRM_103, barrow,85, 416, 160, 464, 208  
27cz1_SLRM_107, celtic_field,84, 96, 448, 224, 576  
27cz1_SLRM_107, barrow,94, 256, 432, 304, 480  
27cz1_SLRM_107, barrow,87, 128, 368, 176, 416  
27cz1_SLRM_107, barrow,84, 64, 304, 112, 352  
27cz1_SLRM_107, barrow,80, 64, 208, 96, 240
```

Example of Coordinate file:

```
27cz1_SLRM_0, 179927.5, 475140.0
27cz1_SLRM_101, 183062.5, 476565.0
27cz1_SLRM_103, 183632.5, 476565.0
27cz1_SLRM_107, 184772.5, 476565.0
```

In order to reduce the number of false positives I want to take out all the single detections of the class `celtic_field`.

In the above example the `celtic_field` detections from `27cz1_SLRM_103` should remain, but the `celtic_field` detection from `27cz1_SLRM_107` should be removed.

As part of the further processing, the CSV is opened as a dictionary and turned into a `GEOJSON` entry (see below). This works fine but I would like to include the above.

```
coords = {}
coords_file = csv.reader(open(coordinate_location))
for row in coords_file:
    coords[row[0]] = [float(row[1]),float(row[2])]

# open output file
output_file = csv.DictReader(open(output_location))

# turn detections into polygons
for row in output_file:

    img_name = row['filename']
    detection_class = row['type'].strip()
    confidence = row['confidence']
    #combo = row['filename'] + row['type']

    #detection_type = detection['tool_label']

    if detection_class == 'celtic_field':
        detectionDict = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": []
            },
            "properties": {
                "detection_type": detection_class,
                "confidence": confidence
            }
        }

        polyCoords = []
        coordinate_x_1 = coords[img_name][0] + float(row['xmin']) * 0.5
        coordinate_x_2 = coords[img_name][0] + float(row['xmin']) * 0.5
        coordinate_x_3 = coords[img_name][0] + float(row['xmax']) * 0.5
        coordinate_x_4 = coords[img_name][0] + float(row['xmax']) * 0.5
        coordinate_y_1 = coords[img_name][1] - float(row['ymin']) * 0.5
        coordinate_y_2 = coords[img_name][1] - float(row['ymax']) * 0.5
        coordinate_y_3 = coords[img_name][1] - float(row['ymax']) * 0.5
        coordinate_y_4 = coords[img_name][1] - float(row['ymin']) * 0.5

        polyCoords.append([coordinate_x_1,coordinate_y_1])
        polyCoords.append([coordinate_x_2,coordinate_y_2])
        polyCoords.append([coordinate_x_3,coordinate_y_3])
        polyCoords.append([coordinate_x_4,coordinate_y_4])
        polyCoords.append([coordinate_x_1,coordinate_y_1])

        detectionDict['geometry']['coordinates'].append(polyCoords)
        output['features'].append(detectionDict)
```

Comment: What about `27cz1_SLRM_107, barrow`, there are **four**. Should remain all **four** or start the fourth a new count cycle?

Comment: All the barrow detections should remain. Only the Celtic field detections should be filtered. if there were 4 Celtic field detections in succession with the same filename they should all remain.

Comment: There is no need to ***"Comparing previous and next "***, simple `.append(...` to a list and write it `if len(<celtic_field_list>) >= 3:`

Comment: How is `coords` defined? Can you give an example?

Comment: @MartinEvans: `coords` are taken from the Geotiff images that are used as input for the CNN:                                                                                              
    `# first get realworld coordinates of top-left corner from pre-saved coordinates file    
    coords = {}  
    coords_file = csv.reader(open(coordinate_location))  
    for row in coords_file:  
        coords[row[0]] = [float(row[1]),float(row[2])]`

Comment: Thanks, it would be better if you use the [edit] button to include that code into your question. If you also included an example of the file, we would be able to run your script.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, this is my first question on Stack Overflow, so I am still learning the ropes...

Comment: Would you be also to add your expected output CSV for that data?

Comment: The output of the script is a Geojson file with the features as points or as polygons...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df['count']=df.groupby(['filename','type']).transform('count')['confidence']

df=df[~((df['count']==1)&(df['type']=='celtic_field'))]
```

print(df)

```
          filename           type  confidence  xmin  ymin  xmax  ymax    count
0     27cz1_SLRM_0         barrow          87   128   176   176     224      1
1   27cz1_SLRM_101         barrow          80   480   400   512     432      1
2   27cz1_SLRM_103   celtic_field          85     0   112    96     256      3
3   27cz1_SLRM_103   celtic_field          80   256   384   384     544      3
4   27cz1_SLRM_103   celtic_field          80   160    96   304     272      3
5   27cz1_SLRM_103         barrow          85   416   160   464     208      1
7   27cz1_SLRM_107         barrow          94   256   432   304     480      4
8   27cz1_SLRM_107         barrow          87   128   368   176     416      4
9   27cz1_SLRM_107         barrow          84    64   304   112     352      4
10  27cz1_SLRM_107         barrow          80    64   208    96     240      4
```

Comment: Thank you, I am trying this now. This solution uses a dataframe, how do you easily convert a dictionary to a dataframe?

Comment: you can use: df=pd.DataFrame(dict), but you told us that hou have a csv file so you can read the csv with pd.read_csv(file.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of many of you (especially Billy Bonaros), I have found a working solution:

```
# remove loose celtic_fields
df = pd.read_csv(output_location)
df['count'] = df.groupby(['filename','type']).transform('count')['confidence']

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['count']==1 and row['type']==' celtic_field':
        df.drop(i, inplace=True)

df.to_csv('...\csv.txt')

# open output file

output_file = csv.DictReader(open('...\csv.txt'))
```

Many thanks!